# How to use "Enter" key insted of "Tab" key in openerp 7 for one2many field

Tags: javascript, jquery, python-2.7, openerp-7, one2many

I am working in sale order line and currently by pressing "Enter" key in one2many field it is creating new line, but I want to do some changes so **Enter** key work as **TAB** key ,It means if I pressed **Enter** key then insted of creating new line it should focus on next field of one2many.

Example:

There are 4 fields in one line so when I pressed enter key it should switch to next field in same line insted of creating new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am giving answer to my question .. Actually I tried and found one solution from the following link:

[From odoo forum](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-make-the-enter-key-work-as-tab-key-1310)

There are some issue which I found in that answer but didn't able to solve that :(

Issues are:

(1) I make change in base model of web in that "**view_list_editable.js**" as                              told in this link insted of my custom model.

(2) Also when any read-only fields is there in between One2Many visible fields then this solution is not working..

Answer (score -2):

Changes "Enter" key behaviour in UI form: jump to next input field instead of doing nothing.

Just use web_returnkey module (by Vadim)and take a look at this answer in ODOO Forum https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/how-to-make-the-enter-key-work-as-tab-key-in-form-view-134811 :

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hdD-C2ppsyQ

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32421514)